# HTML5 p2p communication

Tags: ajax, html, chat, comet, p2p

I am required to build a web application to inject live subtitles on a live stream.
Subtitles will be produced by an operator with a speech-recognition software (or by a typist), filling a textarea on a browser. The consumer will be an HTML5 video tag in a browser.

The rationale is quite simple, probably simpler than a web chat (it's a one-way communication).

This is my current implementation:

- on the producer - when there is some new text - I call via AJAX a writer script on my server, which writes the text on a file.
- on the consumer I continuously call via ajax (using "comet" polling) a reader script on the server, which gives me back the new text, which I inject over the video tag to render the subtitle.

This implementation works, but it looks quite convolute, I'm not quite satisfacted with it...
Any suggestion for a "smarter" or cleaner architecture?

Comment: You do know, "ajax" and "comet" are fundamentally incompatible with p2p, right?  Either you're asking for the impossible or you're misusing the terms.

Comment: The problem is in the class of peer to peer communication. If there *must* be a server in the middle is an architectural issue... I was just asking for a cleaner implementation idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sockets / nodejs. Sockets will open the connection to the browsers for you every time there is new data. No need to poll!

Check [this](http://martinsikora.com/nodejs-and-websocket-simple-chat-tutorial) for example...

Comment: Thanks! But couldn't it cause some issue with firewalls (the application will have to connect different LANs...)?

Comment: No, it shouldnt interfere with firewalls. If the browser can reach the server in the first place ofcourse

Comment: I see... communication on port 1337 happens on the server side, right?